# How can I permanently disable USB debugging mode?

Tags: usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace and I've encountered a strange issue. When I was connecting my mobile to the PC I unchecked the box for "USB debugging mode" and did my work without issue. However, after some time passed and I again tried to connect my mobile to same PC, it was unable to connect. When I checked my settings, I noticed that USB debugging had become re-enabled again. Is there anything I need to set to disable USB debugging permanently, or is this the default behaviour of the Samsung Ace?

Comment: I would uncheck it and then reboot before connecting to anything.

Comment: why reboot, does it actually require...

Comment: No, it shouldn't require that, but I thought it might work.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to myself, you would have to turn the device off several times whilst your USB is connected and just wait for it to stay turned off, once its turned off it will not turn back on unless upon reconnection. It's a very old phone and is not a good phone so this is why it's like this. I wish there was a better resolution myself but after browsing the internet for around an hour I figured I'd help a somebody else and let them know what I know.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that one of these solutions will help you

**Solution #1:**
If you do not have drivers for your phone installed and you do not want to download huge KIES, you can download only the [ADB Interface Drivers](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/Other-DRIVERS-TOOLS/Samsung/SAMSUNG-Android-ADB-Interface-Driver-29505831-for-Vista-Windows-7-Windows-8.shtml) (6.5mb) for your phone. This might solve the issue about USB Debugging turning itself on.

**Solution #2:** Download and install [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en), open it and run the following code inside.

```
adb kill-server
```

this might also help until you reboot your phone.

Comment: Pretty sure `adb kill-server` won't do anything if you run it on the phone, as the server part of the server-client setup only runs on the computer.

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. That helped me when I was using tcp mode to use adb over wifi, and when after wifi reboot computer didn't see my phone either on the network or via cable, then I had to do adb kill-server on my phone to make it recognizable with a cable again